# File with .pptx extension is being downloaded without extension

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, file, url

Here is the function:

```
export const downloadFile = ({
  url,
  content,
  fileName,
  options
})=> {
  const anchor = document.createElement('a');
  const blobUrl = url || URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([content], options));

  anchor.setAttribute('href', blobUrl);
  anchor.setAttribute('download', fileName);
  anchor.click();
};
```

When I call it with `options = { type: 'application/pdf' }` it downloads the `filename.pdf` file, but when the type is `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation`, it downloads `filename` without extension, what's the problem?

Comment: @KJ, yeah, I was trying to do so, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

So, the trouble is in OS, I don't have Power Point installed, that's why Windows is not recognizing the .pptx extension, I have tested the code on the laptop where Power Point is installed and everything works fine, same for MacOS (but it opens the file in Skype XD)